# A fade animation on another gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is actually a rythm game and when a circle enter into a trigger we can make disapear the circle.

```
public class CursorPress : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool canBePressed;
    public KeyCode keyToPress;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
        {
            GameObject target = GameObject.Find("hitcircle_r");

            if(target.tag == "Target")
            {
                if (canBePressed)
                {
                    target.GetComponent<Animation> ().play("hitcircle_fading");
                    target.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Target")
        {
            canBePressed = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Target")
        {
            canBePressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want that when the player press a key (keyToPress), a custom gameObject (hitcircle_r) gets a fade animation before disapearing, but idk how to do it, i tried a lot of code i found on the web, can someone helps me please ?

Comment: You need to wait till the animation finishes before hiding it or it will just pop off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want.
One would be to call a coroutine that fades deactivates your target after time.

If you are only doing fading style animations you should look into DOTween.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CursorPress : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool canBePressed;
    public KeyCode keyToPress;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
        {
            GameObject target = GameObject.Find("hitcircle_r");

            if (target.tag == "Target")
            {
                if (canBePressed)
                {
                    target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("hitcircle_fading");
                    float hideTime = 0.5f; // the length of your animation
                    StartCoroutine(DeactivateTarget(target, hideTime));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Target")
        {
            canBePressed = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Target")
        {
            canBePressed = false;
        }
    }

    // coroutine to deactivate GameObject
    private IEnumerator DeactivateTarget(GameObject targetGo, float hideDelay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(hideDelay);
        targetGo.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```